# Workday SOAP API: Fields not present in response

Tags: integration, soapui, workday-api

I'm trying to get the worker documents data from Workday SOAP API Get_Workers request as outlined here: [Worker_Document_Data](https://community.workday.com/sites/default/files/file-hosting/productionapi/Human_Resources/v40.1/Get_Workers.html#Worker_Document_Data_WWSType)

This is what my request looks like:

```
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:bsvc="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1"
            xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
            xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:UsernameToken>
                <wsse:Username>my_username</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">my_password</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <bsvc:Get_Workers_Request xmlns:bsvc="urn:com.workday/bsvc" bsvc:version="v40.1">
            <bsvc:Response_Filter>
                <bsvc:Count>999</bsvc:Count>
                <bsvc:Page>1</bsvc:Page>
            </bsvc:Response_Filter>
            <bsvc:Response_Group>
                <bsvc:Include_Worker_Documents>true</bsvc:Include_Worker_Documents>
            </bsvc:Response_Group>
        </bsvc:Get_Workers_Request>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But I'm not getting getting the document data in the response, even though I've manually checked through the dashboard and confirmed that documents exist for employees.

All I'm getting in Response_Data is list of this:

```
<wd:Worker>
               <wd:Worker_Data>
                  <wd:Worker_ID>1234</wd:Worker_ID>
                  <wd:User_ID>abcdef</wd:User_ID>
               </wd:Worker_Data>
            </wd:Worker>
```

I'm not getting any kind of error, just not getting the fields when I (imo) should be.

I've manually checked through the dashboard and confirmed that documents exist for employees. Also checked and imo the username/password I'm using has all the required security group persmissions.

Answer (score 0):

whenever something is blank in Workday and you're getting a 200 response, it's pretty much always an issue around not having the right security permissions to view the object.

Specifically for the document section, the API spec you linked to states:

> Contains the documents that were added for a worker during staffing events or ad-hoc. These domains secure this element: Self-Service: Add Worker Documents Self-Service: Edit and Delete Worker Documents Worker Data: Add Worker Documents Worker Data: Edit and Delete Worker Documents

You probably don't need the self-service domains. You can see the data in the UI, so you already have VIEW access to the right domains.

You're missing GET access to those same domains to see the data on a Get_Worker request. I'd start by giving the Workday account you're using GET access to one or both of:

- Worker Data: Add Worker Documents
- Worker Data: Edit and Delete Worker Documents

You also may want to double check you have GET access on these domains:

- Worker Data: Public Worker Reports
- Worker Data: Workers

Once that starts working, if you need to speed up your request, you can try implementing the transaction log. In case it's helpful, I've previously posted some notes around Get_Workers in the past [on my blog](https://sglmr.com/blog/workday-get-workers-notes/).

I hope that helps, good luck!